# Date comparison for same dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My problem is when user selects same dates, query below returns empty array. Instead when user selects same dates, it has to show users created at that date. Any help will be appreciated.

```
User.where("created_at >= ? and created_at =< ?", params[:from].to_date, params[:to].to_date)
```

Comment: You can test whether the two dates are identical. If they are, you can add times and get results between 0:00 and 23:59. If you don't want to use time, you can change the query (when the dates are the same) to find records with date greater than yesterday (date -1) and less than tomorrow (date + 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using DATETIME database columns. The problem is that the user selects "from" as (for example) 2011-07-09 and for the comparison the database translates that to "2011-07-09 00:00:00" and if the user selects the same day twice, there will probably be no results (unless they were exactly created at "2011-07-09 00:00:00"). To fix this, just do

```
to_date = params[to].to_date + 1.day
```

before making the actual database search call. And use to_date instead of params[:to].to_date

Comment: If an answer works for you please mark it as the correct answer.  People will appreciate it and be more willing to help you in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to achieve this:

params[:from].to_date.beginning_of_day
and params[:to].to_date.end_of_day.  This will cover the whole day